# Hibernate stored procedure call results in GenericJDBCException: Invalid column index

Tags: hibernate

In an effort to learn Hibernate 4.1 with Oracle Stored Procedures, I am trying to get an example to work that is as simple as I can make it:
1. No parameters passed in
2. SYS_REFCURSOR as the one return parameter

What I'm getting is an exception: "org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Invalid column index". Searching online for hours for a solution to this has been less than helpful.

============================= Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE IFC_OWNER.JPA_APPLICATION_R_TEST 
(    o_result_set OUT SYS_REFCURSOR  )
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN o_result_set FOR
    SELECT APPLICATION_ID, APP_COMMON_NM, APP_DESC, APP_URL FROM APPLICATION_R;
END;
/
```

============================= xml call

```
<sql-query name="oracleproccall" callable="true">
    <return alias="application_r" class="com.myco.entities.ApplicationR"/>
    <![CDATA[ call JPA_APPLICATION_R_TEST() ]]>
</sql-query>
```

============================= java (Exception thrown at call to sqlQuery.getResultList())

```
public void run() {
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
try {
    Query sqlQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("oracleproccall");
    List list = sqlQuery.getResultList();    
    ...snip...
} catch (PersistenceException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    entityManager.close();
}    
}
```

============================= Entity class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "APPLICATION_R", schema = "IFC_OWNER")
    public class ApplicationR implements Serializable {
        private int applicationId;
        private String appCommonNm;
        private String appDesc;
        private String appUrl;
        ...snip...
More available if needed.
```

============================= Exception

```
## ApplicationsByStoredProc ##
Hibernate: 
    /* named native SQL query oracleproccall */ call JPA_APPLICATION_R_TEST()
Feb 19, 2013 2:58:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 17003, SQLState: 99999
Feb 19, 2013 2:58:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Invalid column index
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Invalid column index
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:266)
    at com.myco.jpa.tests.ApplicationsByStoredProc.run(ApplicationsByStoredProc.java:37)
    at com.dstoutput.jpa.JPAEntities_InFactDomain_Test.main(JPAEntities_InFactDomain_Test.java:56)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Invalid column index
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.CallableStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(CallableStatementProxyHandler.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy16.registerOutParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect.registerResultSetOutParameter(Oracle8iDialect.java:507)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do the construct with the stored procedure? Why you do not put the select from the stored procedure into an HQL statement?

Comment: @Johanna I'm trying to learn the stored procedure because the system I'm converting contains a fair amount of business logic in the existing stored procedures. Obviously, there are any number of ways to do this without a stored procedure and I've done it other ways.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I was using a javax.persistence version of the Session and Query classes and not the org.hibernate version; javax.persistence does not support Oracle Stored Procedure calls while Hibernate does.
The difference is subtle without the import statements provided below. 
The give away should have been the use of the sqlQuery.getResultList(). This is a JPA method call that does not exist in the Hibernate version of Query.

import import javax.persistence.Query;

Query sqlQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("oracleproccall");
List list = sqlQuery.getResultList();

The construct for using the Hibernate version is query.list() not query.getResultList():

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import com.myco.entities.ApplicationR


private void anotherTest() {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session s = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();

    List<AppR> apps;
    Query namedQuery = s.getNamedQuery("oraclestoredproc");
    apps = namedQuery.list();
    apps = s.getNamedQuery("oraclestoredproc").list();
    Iterator<ApplicationR> iterator = apps.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        ApplicationR app = (ApplicationR) iterator.next();
        System.out.print(app.getApplicationId() + " ");
        System.out.print(app.getAppCommonNm() + " ");
        System.out.print(app.getAppDesc() + " ");
        System.out.println(app.getAppUrl() + " ");
    }
    s.flush();
    tx.commit();
    s.close();
}
```

Thanks to Jitu Ji and to this [source](http://www.coderanch.com/t/466425/ORM/databases/Working-Hibernate-Call-Oracle-Stored)

Comment: Note also: If you have an EntityManager object, you can get a org.hibernate.Session like this:  Session s = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);